# Cake PHP Log permissions erro

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i have one issue on cake PHP and Angular5 webapp. After migrating PHP on release 7.12 i got this message when i try to save some data:

```
           failed to open stream: Permission
         denied in /var/www/data/back-end/releases
/20170712150145/back-end/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/
    src/Log/Engine/FileLog.php on line 133
```

here is my permissions:

[image: FOlder permissions on www data]

Comment: check the permission

Answer (score 0):

Issue is related to libssl. Follow this thread i'm able to solve the issue.

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001